# Is there ipv6-only dns?

Tags: linux, dns, ipv6, lxc

I have a system with ipv6 only connectivity.  I'd disable ipv4 altogether, except it's pretty hard to remove, and stome stuff wants to talk to 127.0.0.1.  It's a Linux system, running in an LXC container, with bridged networking.  I'm only trying to communicate with ipv6 hosts, but some of those hosts also have ipv4 addresses.  So, a typical communication session goes like this:

my host -> DNS:
query foo.example.com

DNS -> my host:
foo.example.com A 1.2.3.4
foo.example.com AAAA 2001:DB8::1234

My host -> 1.2.3.4
 (network error)

My host -> 2001:DB8::1234
  (works)

So what I'd like to do is, for instance, block my host from seeing A records, since I don't care about them, they don't benefit me, and they slow things down and cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

Some trick with `ip route preference` will probably allow you to make ipv6 routes preferred to ipv4 routes (I thought there was a more global setting, but just now reading the man page didn't find it).  That means that when you get back both kinds of addresses it should try the ipv6 ones first.  That should make things work.  If you ever try an ipv4 only host, it will try to talk via ipv4, but that will fail.

WARNING: I've never done *exactly* this.  I have used (the predecessor to) `ip route preference` to prefer one ipv4 route to another, but not for ipv6 preference. So YMMV.